# NSArray or NSMutableArray for NSNumber Listing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, arrays, nsarray, nsnumber

Okay, so I want to do something like this:

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

How would I go about that if I want to use NSArray and NSNumbers instead of ints?

**Note:

I do not want something like

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject: ];
```

I need to be able to put them all in a single set separated by a comma.  (Weird but it makes my program easier to handle in that format.  I'm mimicking some java code where that is done a lot, so itl make it easier to follow the tutorial.)

Comment: ...and what have you tried? Looking at the `NSArray` docs for five seconds should give you the answer to this.

Comment: Coming soon to Xcode (probably 4.4), you will be able to use `@[ @1, @2, @3, @4, @5 ]`.

Comment: Sweetness.  Thanks for that info! :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to add all the elements at once, and you're not going to change it, then us an NSArray.  You can fill it like this:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:2],[NSNumber numberWithInt:3],[NSNumber numberWithInt:4],[NSNumber numberWithInt:5],nil];
```

Answer (score 6):

```
NSArray *array = @[@1,@2,@3,@4];
```

Answer (score 1):

you could either do this

```c
NSArray* array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:2],[NSNumber numberWithInt:3],[NSNumber numberWithInt:4], nil];
```